# How can I make Istio recognize k8s Ingress?

Tags: istio, lets-encrypt, cert-manager, istio-gateway

I am trying to use cert-manager with Let's Encrypt to issue certificates using HTTP-01 challenge.

It looks like routing problem - certificate is stuck on domain control validation with error: `Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: wrong status code '304', expected '200'`. Route to application (oauth2-proxy) is working so it responds with `403` - standard for `oauth2-proxy`.

Software stack:

- Istio installed using `helm` version 1.19.3 (`base` + `istiod` in namespace `istio-system`, `gateway` in separate one `istio-ingress-public` - just like in Istio docs)
- cert-manager installed using `helm` version 1.13.2 in namespace `cert-manager`
- application itself (oauth2-proxy) in namespace `oauth2-proxy`
- `hello-kubernetes` for testing purposes
- k8s version 1.26.4

For both `oauth2-proxy` and `hello-kubernetes` I have native Istio `Gateway` and `VirtualService` for each one of them in their namespaces and it works.

For `cert-manager` I have created `Issuer`.

I have created `Certificate` in namespace `oauth2-proxy` and cert-manager created `CertificateRequest`, `Order`, `Challenge` and `Ingress`, `Service` and `Pod` to handle verification.

I have created `IngressClass` for Istio:

```
kubectl get IngressClass -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: IngressClass
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: "2023-11-03T12:12:09Z"
    generation: 1
    name: istio
    resourceVersion: "4756892"
    uid: cd6205b9-e818-48dd-8882-59c6d038e28e
  spec:
    controller: istio.io/ingress-controller
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
```

`Ingress` has `.spec.ingressClassName` set to `istio`:

```
kubectl get Ingress -o yaml -n oauth2-proxy
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
    creationTimestamp: "2023-11-03T14:03:42Z"
    generateName: cm-acme-http-solver-
    generation: 1
    labels:
      acme.cert-manager.io/http-domain: "1390741491"
      acme.cert-manager.io/http-token: "1315376821"
      acme.cert-manager.io/http01-solver: "true"
    name: cm-acme-http-solver-4z6kk
    namespace: oauth2-proxy
    ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: acme.cert-manager.io/v1
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
      controller: true
      kind: Challenge
      name: oauth2-proxy-cert-staging-1-2829224423-1571648249
      uid: 95daf075-ee7e-465e-b129-9d99218addf1
    resourceVersion: "4774848"
    uid: e6a15d62-e010-4b16-8ee0-86bf809e5365
  spec:
    ingressClassName: istio
    rules:
    - host: apps.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: cm-acme-http-solver-spkrv
              port:
                number: 8089
          path: /.well-known/acme-challenge/************
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
```

I followed docs for integrating Istio with cert-manager: [Istio / cert-manager](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/certmanager/) and how to deal with k8s `Ingress`: [Istio / Kubernetes Ingress](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/).

I've also tried to use `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation with same result - no new routes.

What am I doing wrong? From docs it seems that `Ingress` with `.spec.ingressClassName` set to `istio` should be handled without any other configuration. Is there any flag to be set like in previous Istio versions? I didn't find it in `helm` values...

What should happen after creating `Ingress`? I assume that new route should be created and visible using `istioctl`. Should Istio create new `VirtualService`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out.

This issue helped me: [Certificate Challenges failing with Istio + Istio Gateway when installed via Helm · Issue #37329 · istio/istio (github.com)](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/37329)

Istio configuration depends on how you installed it. And if installed using helm you need to configure few values to make it work. Of course values may change depending on your environment - but without setting them Istio does not recognize `Ingress` resources.

```
  set {
    name  = "meshConfig.ingressService"
    value = "istio-ingress"
  }
  set {
    name  = "meshConfig.ingressSelector"
    value = "ingress"
  }
```

When properly configured, Istio will create `VirtualService` to handle challenge and you should be able to debug Istio config using `istioctl`:

```
// list ingress gateways
$ istioctl proxy-status

// show routes
$ istioctl proxy-config routes -n <ingress_gateway_namespace> <ingress_gateway_name_from_previous_command>
```